# Bing map v7 adding infobox to georss parser module

Tags: bing-maps

Using this plugin ([source](http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/19597#50537)) to load pins from an xml file, pins get added correctly, but now trying to add infoboxes to each respective pin.

In the function that receives the array of pins I'm trying to loop through each item and add infoboxes accordingly.  Any ideas as to what I'm missing here?

```
      function GeoRSSImportedCallback(items, bounds) {
          map.entities.push(items);

          for (var i = 0; i<items.length; i++) {
            items[i].Title = items[i].title;
            items[i].Description = items[i].description;
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(itmes[i], 'click', displayInfoBox);
          }

          map.entities.push(infoboxLayer);
          map.setView({ bounds: bounds });
      }

    function displayInfoBox(e) {
        pinInfoBox.setOptions({title: e.target.Title, description: e.target.Description, visible:true, offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0,25)});
        pinInfoBox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
}
```

I do initialize the following in the `GetMap()` function

```
        pinInfoBox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), { visible: false });
        infoboxLayer.push(pinInfoBox);
```